# clean a div of a specified css rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a website, I have a header and footer that comes from another website.

Those header and footers came with javascript and add lots of CSS files (CSS files used from another website) ... and the main website too!
Those CSS are like battle themselves and the rendreing of the header and footer are like mixed styles because of mixing CSS rules from all css files...

How Can I remove all the CSS rules (main.css) on the two part of the main website and just apply the "headerAndFooter.css" on those two parts?

The every part havs his proper div.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well without seeing any code or examples this might be difficult. But can't you just delete the sections you aren't using from the CSS files?

Comment: Are you displaying cross-domain content using an `iframe` by any chance?

Comment: @CalvinScherle : I can't edit the CSS that come with header and footer.

Comment: @kei I can't use iFrame because the height of the header/footer can change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally download the incoming CSS and prefix them by #header and #footer. Than I ahave full control of all CSS because I use it locally.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new class for your headers and footers in a separate CSS file - and enter the needed styles there.  That way, they won't conflict with the rest of your site - and you won't compromise the rest of your site's layout by modifying global CSS.

Of course, without seeing any of your code, it's hard to provide a detailed answer, but in cases like this, more accurate class names are a good starting point.

Comment: To add to this answer, I'd suggest putting a master class on the body of this site. You would then repeat the rules you want to reset with the master class prepending all of them. That way this won't affect the site it is pulling from, just the end result of the current one.

Comment: @Stan The two websites are already done, the website that give header/footer and the main website, so I just search the way to disable the main.css for the two div (header + footer)

Comment: @clement, I understand that, but disabling certain CSS for certain pages or certain elements can quickly make a mess and the code won't be reusable, so it is better to do what I said and either modify the existing files or create a new file with more specific classes so you don't have to resort to this approach in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important` at the end of the value of the property you are trying to change, if you have several rules overwriting each other.

For example: the blue color would show, not the red, because you labeled the blue as important.

```
body {
    color:red;
}

body {
    color:blue !important;
}
```

A better solution would be to just erase the rules that you don't need from the different css files.

Comment: there are more than 1000 lines in each CSS, I will not put !important on each line of one CSS, it will affect the other website